# How to assign a variable a new object

Tags: c++, variables, object, constructor, variable-assignment

Let's say I have a line of code like this:

```
MyClass obj(1, 2, "hello");
```

And at some point in the future I want to assign `obj` a new value, i.e. `obj(3, 4, "bye")`. How to do this?

I mean in **Java** I would do this:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass(1, 2, "hello");
obj = new MyClass(3, 4, "bye");
```

In **C++** I have tried this:

```
MyClass obj(1, 2, "hello");
obj(3, 4, "bye");
```

But it didn't work, so I also have tried this:

```
MyClass obj(1, 2, "hello");
obj = MyClass(3, 4, "bye");
```

And it actually did work, but I am not sure if this is the preferred way to achieve this.

Please suggest me a clean way to assign a variable a new object and tell me if there is any additional effort needed to manage the memory after such an assignment.

Please keep in mind that I have started learning **C++** two days ago, but I know **OOP** concepts as good as I know how many fingers my hands have.

Comment: The second thing you tried is fine and idiomatic. You can also provide methods to change the values of the members.

Comment: @juanchopanza I haven't seen any examples of this in the http://www.cplusplus.com tutorials so I thought that this is not a good way to do it. But what if I am using a `stringstream` object, i.e. `stringstream ss(line); ss = stringstream(anotherline);`. Is this also good?

Comment: cplusplus.com is not exactly awesome. As for `stringstream`, that would work, but only since C++11. Before that, you could not copy or assign that type.

Comment: Yes, your last attempt is actually the way it is normally done. No memory management needed, except possibly as required by the class itself. If you use no explicit `new` in your class, you probably need not worry. This example has nothing to do with OOP so you may want to count your fingers again, just in case.

Comment: @n.m. I didn't mean that THIS example has something to do with OOP. I meant that I am already familiar with OOP so you may feel free to explain me anything about how the variables are usually assigned objects and how they are allocated in C++, because I was asking about possible memory management effort.

Comment: OOP begins when you override a parent's method in a child class. If you don't have child classes, there's no OOP. Here's what you need to know before doing any OOP in C++: you only work with pointers or references. Thid code `MyClass obj(1, 2, "hello"); obj = MyClass(3, 4, "bye");` is right but this `MyClass obj(1, 2, "hello"); obj = MyChildClass(3, 4, "bye");` is *wrong*. `MyClass* obj= new MyClass(1, 2, "hello"); ... obj = new MyChildClass(3, 4, "bye");` is right again (but you really should use smart pointers instead of built in ones).

Answer (score 4):

The code in C++ that is similar to the Java code

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass(1, 2, "hello");
obj = new MyClass(3, 4, "bye");
```

will look like

```
MyClass *obj = new MyClass(1, 2, "hello");
delete obj;
obj = new MyClass(3, 4, "bye");
```

The way you are using for assigning an object in C++ like

```
MyClass obj(1, 2, "hello");
obj = MyClass(3, 4, "bye");
```

is valid provided that there is a valid copy or move assignment operator defined in the class.

Comment: This looks much better. I like your approach. But what if I don't use `delete obj;` before assigning it a new one? Is the old object leaked without a possibility to delete it later?

Comment: @Salivan C++ has no a garbage collector. So there will be a memory leak.

Comment: @Salivan: That approach is certainly not much better. It's equivalent to the Java in the sense that it does something similar to what the Java code does. However, it is not equivalent in the sense that it is a correct or good or sensible thing to do. There are very few reasons to ever use `new` or `delete` in C++. In user code, it can and should be avoided completely.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley So you say that I should rely on using `obj = MyClass(3, 4, "bye");`?

Comment: @Salivan: Either that, or your class should have member functions which modify it accordingly.